# How many claims can a Role/User have in ASP.Net.Core.Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How many claims can a role or user have? I've been working on an app using ASP.Net.Core 2.2 and AspNet.Core.Identity. All works fine until testing on my browser. Under debugging in VS2019 there is no such problem.

I deployed my app for further testing and run into this error (below). I have the same problem in IE, GC and FF.

```
HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.
```

I'm using `Roles` and `RoleClaims`

After some digging around I find its to do with Role/Claims in the fact there are too many of them that it blows the cache. Basically `Identity` in trying to store all the claims in a cookie and the cookie is now just too big.

It just seems really odd that Microsoft would give you all that complexity only to have yo thwarted by the browser.

So my questions are:
 - What's the point of roles/claims if you can' exploit them because of browser restrictions?
 - It's there anything documented on the imaginary limit (max no. of claims per role)?

Comment: I have an asp.net core 3.0 application with 100+ roles and no problem.

Comment: not just roles, roles and claims. in my testing i have only one role with around 20 claims for that role

Comment: @MariusSteinbach, would you be willing to share your solution to the problem. I've done nothing clever with asp.net.identity, it's pretty much used as it comes out of the box. The only thing I have changed is user id from guid(string) to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know I could not get ITicketStore to work no matter what I tried. I even spent several days reading all the documents I could find on ITicketStore, it's not very well documented at all. And this seems like quite a common problem (the cookie thing and ITicketStore documentation).

Anyway, I changed my application so that Asp.Net.Identity only picks up the user role. This solves the cookie size problem.

I've implemented my own functions to check the role-claims. Which works better I feel as any changes happen live so no need to log on/off to get new claims or revoke existing claims.

I have a service function, that takes an `IdentityUser<AppUser>` and a Claim name (string).

```
_adminService.UserHasClaim(user, ClaimName) // returns true or false if you have that claim or not
```

I have my own table, identical to the AspNetRoleClaims table that contains the values. The Asp.Net.Identity version of that table is now empty so the cookie doesn't contain any claims.

```
    public bool UserHasClaim(AppUser user, string claimValue)
    {
        var claim = (from c in _context.AppUserRoleClaims
                     join t in _context.AppUserClaimTypes on c.ClaimID equals t.ID
                     join r in _context.UserRoles on c.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                     where r.UserId == user.Id && t.ClaimValue == claimValue select c).FirstOrDefault();

        return (claim != null);
    }
```

It might not be perfect or ideal but it works and I can't afford any more time trying to solve this using identity. I don't claim it to be ideal and I'll probably come back to it later in time.

Happy to take comments on a better workable solution, but for now that's how I've solved the problem.

So, moving on ...

Comment: So you don't use AuthorizeAttribute and Roles ( [Authorize(Roles = "role1")] ) ? You just check in code ?

Comment: Yep :) I have a function called `IsInRole(...)` that handles that check for me. Because I want a quite detailed security model and there are lot of roles, it was blowing things up trying to store them all in a cookie

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into it, trying to make it work with my existing role/action system, and was amazed how dumb they made it. I am horrified. And this is after decade of "improvements"...

Answer (score 1):

The restriction is not imaginary, and it's not browser-based. The request limit is set by the server and is a security measure. As such, it's really not a good idea to attempt to increase the limit.

Additionally, there's no real guidance that can be given here about something like max number of claims, because it's based on variables: type and size of the individual claims, and other parts of the request, like additional headers that may or may not be added at any given time. However, the limit is usually 8-32K, and even on the low-end, that's still quite a lot of claims you should be able to add before hitting the limit. You should also consider the transfer size, in general. Claims are part of the authentication ticket, which means the client must transfer them with each request. 8K per request may not seem like a lot, but can add up significantly over the life of a user's session, and particular if the user is on slow or capped data connections.

Long and short, the best thing you should do here is reduce the amount of claims. Not everything needs to be or should be a claim. Store additional data on the user profile and query it as necessary. The only thing you absolutely should have as claims are key things like id, username/email, and roles. Anything else can always get pull from an alternate store later if or when you need it.

There is also an option to use an alternate store to actually hold the auth ticket data, in the first place. Instead of sending everything down as a cookie, which then must be sent back with each request, you can simply send an identifier and then pull the actual data based on that, similar to how sessions work. This is done by creating an implementation of `ITicketStore` and setting that for [`CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.sessionstore?view=aspnetcore-3.0). There's an [old sample for using cache as the store](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/samples/CookieSessionSample). You may need to modify the code for new versions of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for that Chris. Its funny you should say because before asp.net.identity i used to role my own security which worked in a similar way to which you described. The only thing that got pushed around was a small ID token and that was all managed by some action filters and simply checked security each time you wanted to do something. I had attributes like identity does and it all worked great. i switched to identity because every one was raving about how good it was and thats the way i should go

Comment: ps, yes I'll have to modify because right now it doesn't work and creates a huge 9 chunk cookie. coincidentally probably explains why the app does't work locally on GC and IE but does on FF

Comment: I've been looking at ITicketStore for a few days now and not making much progress. All I can find are implementations that don't work and I can make neither hide nor hair of whats going on. I can't even find and tutorial. Interestingly ITicket store brings up articles about cigarettes after sex which I thought was funny

Comment: Chris - what about in Blazor server? Do those limits still hold or does it keep everything on the server side allowing numerous claims? Because I have to set up a ton of claims one way or another - but need to keep it on the server side.

Comment: @DavidThielen With Blazor server the first request uses cookies when the user first sets up the circuit. After that, you're free to handle it on the server in a separate service as you want. I made a Permission service that retrieves requested permissions from a DB and caches it in memory for fast access when rendering pages containing a lot of elements with permissions. My permissions mgt page invalidates those cache entries when they are modified so they are applied immediately. You can handle a metric ton of claims this way. Of course you have to be careful with security leaks though.

Comment: @AMG so that first cookie based request - not going to see a ton of claims? But the subsequent ones are ok?  
And the DB has a "metric ton" of claims but the user has 3 - 4 claims. So will the initial cookie request have just that user's claims? TIA

Answer (score 0):

any claim (role,email,id ...) on identity, has a name/Type. the default of names/Types are url. and after serializing claims, this names increased the size of cookie .
I set these three propertie

```
services.AddIdentity<User, TRole>(opt => 
            {
                opt.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "Role";
                opt.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "ID";
                opt.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "UserName";
                opt.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = "Email";
            });
```

and size of my cookie decreased to less than half of defaults